# Find the RMS value of the periodic triangular current, if Im=1A, T=1s

Tags: ac, rms

Find the RMS value of the periodic triangular current, if I_m=1A, T=1s.
[image]

Could you tell me step-by-step how to do this? It's not a homework, I just want to find out how to solve this problem.

Comment: We don't just give you the answers to homework problems here, but will help you find the solution if you show some effort on your own. Also, the question is ambiguous. What is "effective value"?

Comment: Look up "Root Mean Square". Hint: You will need to integrate the area under any arbitrary current curve as a first step. Much simpler, almost trivial, with the triangular wave shown. Not going to do a step-by-step for you, sorry.

Comment: @Anindo: You are making a possibly invalid assumption about what the OP means by "effective value". Answering a question like that is irresponsible and possibly wrong. We also need to insist the OP ask properly before getting anything useful.

Comment: Yes, I mean RMS.
I know there's a special formula for this. It's a root square from (1/T)*interal from 0 to T from i(t)^2

Comment: I don't have i(t), but I have a graph. How to "put" this graph into this integral?

Comment: @OlinLathrop In several of the textbooks used in our college days, the term "Effective Value" was **defined** as "Root Mean Square value", to wit, the value which effectively is equivalent to an identical DC value in terms of power dissipation across a purely resistive load. The only other use of the term that I know of is "Effective instantaneous value", which obviously isn't relevant in this case.

Comment: @TomDavies92 You integrate a cyclic graph with linear segments by simply adding up the areas under each such line segment across the period of the graph.

Comment: so the area under the graph from 0 to T is 1. So the effective value is 1A?

Comment: I've never heard the term "effective area" used for RMS in America. You might get more responses if you edit the question to include this definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMS means "root mean square", in the order root(mean(square(paramter)).

First, square the function.  The find the mean: that requires analysis (calculus). To find the mean value of a function \$f(x)\$ on some interval \$[a, b]\$, you integrate the function on that integral: \$\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)dx\$ and then divide by the interval: \$\displaystyle\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx\$.

The waveform you are working with has a lot of symmetry. Basically, you can divide it into up and down ramp segments: each one has the same mean square value. So write the function for just one of the ramps (without loss of generality, the first one that passes through the origin). This is of the form \$y = Ax\$.  When you square that you get \$A^2x^2\$. Integrate that from \$x = 0\$ to the value of \$x\$ that produces the peak and do the division to get the mean square value.

After that, the root means square value is just that: the (square) root of the mean square value.

Comment: so I write a line passing (0,0) and (1/4, 2) => it's y=8x. Now I square it: 64x^2. Then I need to integrate it from 0 to 1/4, I get 1/3. Now I multiply 1/3 * 4 and root it. So I get 2/sqrt(3). Am I right?

Comment: @TomDavies92 It sounds right, and the figure is in the right ballpark. We expect it to be between 0 and 2. And it should be more than one, because of the squaring; if it was 1, it would just be the mean current, not the RMS (power-related) current.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you've clarified you want to find the RMS value, a concrete answer is possible.  Note that by symmetry, each of the line segments of this triangle wave will have the same RMS value.  Note also that the time scale is irrelevant.

So, the question really comes down to *"What is the RMS value of a linear ramp from 0 to 2 A?"*.  To answer this, go back to the definition of RMS, which is the square root of the average of the square.  That means to perform the RMS calculation, you square the signal, average it, then take the square root of that average.

You should be able to write the equation for the square of the linear ramp from inspection.  Since the linear ramp is a first order function, you know this square will be second order, or a parabola.  Once you have the equation for the parabola, you can integrate it and divide by the integration period to get the average.  Then it's just taking the square root of the result.  I've given you the basic method, but this is your homework assignment, so you have to do the actual work.